# android converting activities to fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have made a nice app with a whole bunch of `activities` , then i needed a `navigation drawer` and found out that you need to have only one `activity` for the whole app and the individual different screens should be `fragments` that are inserted at runtime.

my question is :

How to convert the entire app to use `fragments` instead of `activities` ? (eg: how to preserve activity hierarchy , show a main activity when the user opens the app , different actionbar for each screen , etc...)

Comment: There is no one line fix to convert all activities to fragments. You will have to create new fragments for each of your activities and handle the navigation and stack management yourself. To be frank, this should have been considered even before you wrote your first line of code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic converter, you need to convert manually each activity to be extended from Fragment
and add few must methods like onCreateView for the fragment instead of SetContentView of activity.

Regarding the actionbars, it sits on the **Main** Activity so you need to create callback events from each fragment to the main activity in order to control the action bar.

Answer (score 1):

Navigation drawer has nothing related to fragments.

If you wish you can put it into activities also.

What I created was a **BaseActivity** with layout having navigation drawer and all other activities **extend BaseActivity** so that each of your activity will have drawer. Only you need to change content page for particular activity.

happy coding.

Comment: what do you mean? in `BaseActivity` you do `setContentView` ? but then you can't `setContentView` on the child activity.

Comment: you can create some function in baseActivity to inflate content layout which will be called from child activity.

Comment: In baseActivity you set the layout using fragments , correct?

Comment: If so than your child activity should actually be a fragment